# Adding widgets to a WooCommerce sidebar using product tags conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

I'm using WooCommerce on my Wordpress site as a catalogue (i.e. with the cart disabled) and I want to add widgets to the single product page sidebar based on if the product has a certain tag or not. I tried using the "Widget Logic" plugin and conditional tags, but even if I disabled all other plugins I could not get this to work anywhere on the site (i.e. including with a tagged post and the main sidebar - so not just with a tagged product in WooCommerce).

I then added the "PHP Code Widget" and added the code below in it:

```
    <?php
if (is_product_tag( 'adexample1' )) {
echo "test1";
} elseif (is_product_tag( 'adexample2' )){
echo "test2";    
} elseif (is_product_tag( 'adexample3' )){
echo "test3";  
} elseif (is_product_tag( 'adexample4' )){
echo "test4";  
} elseif (is_product_tag( 'adexample5' )){
echo "test5";  
} else {
echo "<p>test6</p>";
}
?>
```

I've tested it with the tagged products and the other products, but they all return "test6" in the widget.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong or is it possible that the product tags are not working/being recognised for some reason (permissions perhaps?). The issue is replicated in the default 2017 and basic WooCommerce themes, so it doesn't appear to be a theme issue?

Suggestions for another way of achieving this would also be appreciated?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional [**`is_product_tag()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-6) will not work to get a product that has a product tag, as it's used to return true when viewing a product tag archive page.

To do achieve what you want to do you need to use WordPress [**`has_term()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) conditional function with defined $taxonomy argument to **`'product_tag'`**, this way:

```
// Define BELOW your product tag ID, slug or name (or an array of values)
$term = 'adexample1';
$term2 = 'adexample2'; // ...

// HERE are your conditions with your code
if( has_term( $term, 'product_tag' ) ){
    echo "test1";
} elseif( has_term( $term2, 'product_tag' ) ){
    echo "test1";
} else {
    echo "<p>test6</p>";
}
```

This should work as it works for product categories with defined $taxonomy argument to **`'product_cat'`**…

Comment: That worked perfectly and your feedback is very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @Riverbum75 You are welcome… That was the first time I used `has_term()` function with WooCommerce product tags… But it was logical that if it's working with product categories taxonomy, it will work with product tags taxonomy too…